# Modal with iframe in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to open iframe within modal-body. I am adding src dynamically. But its adding url of main background page to the opened URL.

What I have tried is?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade modal-box myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xlg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3 class="margin-none" id="myModalLabel"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Hi User, How are you??
                        <iframe src="about:blank" style="zoom:0.80" frameborder="0" height="250" width="99.6%"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a data-url="http%3A%2F%2Ftimesofindia.indiatimes.com%2Fentertainment%2Fhindi%2Fbollywood%2FKangana-Ranauts-interesting-statements%2Fphotostory%2F47070425.cms" data-news-source="Times of India" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:;">Kangana Ranaut's interesting statements</a>


$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var heading = e.relatedTarget.dataset.newsSource,
            newsUrl = e.relatedTarget.dataset.url,
            $modal = $(this);
    $("#myModalLabel").html("News Source - " + heading);
    $('iframe').attr({src: newsUrl});
    console.log(newsUrl);
});
```

Its giving error on console that the requested url : http://localhost/desibazar/news/%27http%3A%2F%2Ftimesofindia.indiatimes.com%2Fentertainment%2Fhindi%2Fbollywood%2FKangana-Ranauts-interesting-statements%2Fphotostory%2F47070425.cms%27" is not found on server.

Second issue is its adding css rule to modal-header as dom is completed. Show its not showing modal-header in my ModalBox.

Comment: did it not occur to you to decode the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the `'`from your iframe call and decode the URL and it should work :

```
$('iframe').attr({src: decodeURIComponent(newsUrl)});
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to hide the close button you just have to keep the button element and hide it with javascript :

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    ...
    $(this).find('.modal-header button.close').css('display','none');
    ...
});
```

And then to enable it you have to use this code :

```
$('#myModal').find('.modal-header button.close').css('display','block');
```

Comment: Its works now after usign decodeURIComponent. But why its closign model-header after once opening the modelBox??

Comment: What do you want to says with **its closign model-header**? Can you explaint that or add a screenshot ?

Comment: Yes its slidingUp my model-header element by adding inline style"display:none". I am not able to trace it. Is there any way we can trace ELement changes via javascript? Is they anyfirebug trick so we can watch this element. Because I am not adding so. 

Main thing is, it first open the ModelBox properly then close the model-header element.

Comment: If you want to disable animation on modal, you just have to remove the `fade`class on your modal element

Comment: I wish to disable the closing of model-header element.

Comment: Simply remove the `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>` element

Comment: I misunderstand your question. Please insert again the `button` element and follow my updated post.